# How to set the background image of gridlayout for each row in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an application in which i wantt to set each row of gridlayout with different image

Comment: What have you tried? Did you encounter any problems? You should include these kinds of information in your question.

Comment: You can try tablelayout instead of gridlayout so that you can set background image for each row.

Comment: try some googling buddy ..its a basic thing in android

Comment: So, what you want from us ?? You should try first and if you are facing any problems we can help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a array list of images file path/url and simply call it from inside your getView method like

```
layoutName.setBackground(imageList.get(position));
```